# Yaml Syntax - can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key

Tags: yaml

I have a `.yaml` file like this:

```yaml
title: 'We'll do cool stuff'
draft: true
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing YAML: YAMLException: can not read a block mapping entry; 
a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 2, column 6:

  draft: true
       ^
```

How can I fix it?

**Note**: this setup seems different than the other questions where this same error was raised, including the following posts:

- [Error parsing YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68343620/1366033)
- [Getting following error on serverless.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55939474/1366033)
- [yaml syntax issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68039278/1366033)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a site like [YAML Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter) to format and *validate* your yaml:

[image: yaml formatter example]

In this case, the error message and location is a bit of red-herring.

The error is actually caused by a string that was accidentally terminated because of an unescaped quote symbol within the string.  A hint for this is the syntax highlighting of `'We'll do cool stuff'`.

To fix, in this case, you can just skip wrapping the string quotes and rewrite like this:

```yaml
title: We'll do cool stuff
draft: true
```

#### Further Reading

- [Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19109912/1366033)
- [How to escape double and single quotes in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37427498/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

```
title: "We'll do cool stuff"
draft: true
```

I have got the exact same issue, The problem with it is, we are using a single quote`'` in between the string and also wrapping the string with a single quote.
I resolved it by wrapping the string with a double quote.

[You can also trace the issue more by reading this](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/1156#issuecomment-944695193)